# Windows XP installation problems

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I recently asked a question on here, and thought I had it working... Here is a link to it.

[Windows XP Installation problems](https://superuser.com/questions/227539/windows-xp-installation-problems)

So basically I'm having trouble getting XP installed. To sum it up, a computer I have had a boot sector virus, and I used Darik's Nuke and Boot to wipe the hard drive clean.

So the hard drive has nothing on it. I had to try and install Windows through a DOS prompt, because for some reason it won't read it off the DVD.  The UBCD is able to look at the files located on the DVD I have in, but I can't boot from it for some reason.  So I extracted it to a USB drive, booted to DOS and started the setup process.

Here's the weird thing with DOS... It can only find the C: drive. The C: drive in DOS is the flash drive that I have in, running DOS. I can't find the hard drive anywhere!

So anyways, after starting the setup process, it copied the files over to the "hard drive" (which took 16 hours because the version of DOS I ran couldn't run smartdrv.exe), and it said the computer had to reboot. So I let it reboot, and it stopped and said there is no boot device.  So I popped in UBCD that I have installed on a flash drive, and I discovered that it had copied the Windows files over to the flash drive and not the hard drive. It never asked where it should extract the files...

So I toyed around with UBCD, ran a memory test on the hard drive to make sure it was fine, and it came out clean.

So I'm stuck now. How can I get this installed?

Writing this, I came up with an idea. If I copy the DOS startup files over to the hard drive, would I be able to start DOS from it? If so, I believe that could fix my problems.

Any help is greatly appreciated, because I am running out of ideas and am at my wits end with this computer.

Comment: Yes you can boot to DOS and start the windows CD installation from there. But it's easiest to do that with a floppy disk or USB stick. It is a little bit trickier to do it all from C.  In the old days of floppy boot disks(or in your case, USB stick), people would do it by booting DOS from that then from there making C bootable with DOS boot files.  So you see your booting DOS from hard drive plan will be more difficult for you than your booting DOS from usb stick or floppy disk plan.  And by the way. DOS can't naturally see NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP should not be on an installation DVD it should be on an installation CD.  The boot sector from an XP CD doesn't work if you simply drop it on a DVD(i know, i tried it a LOOOONG time ago before i started worshipping at the linux and BSD temples ;) ).  Try putting the data on a CD and copying the right bootsector on there.  Poweriso or magiciso should be able to do it for you.

Comment: Got it working, burned it on a cd and everything is running smoothly. Thanks a lot for the help!